# admob in unity don't show

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

the ad does not show. as i debug i found that the ad has not been loaded, but it has request seen by report. my account has crate a month and i had verify it around 2 day. so i think is not the account problem, so i don't know why i has request the ad but the ad not being loaded.
and i use 2020.1.3f1 version of unity and Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v5.4.0
someone can solve my problem please.
[image]

it is my report from admob.

Answer (score 0):

## You could get banned for this!

If you get ad request in your AdMob dashboad after starting Ad in unity editor; It means you are not using the **Test Ads**!

When you test your ads you should use the **Test Ads Ids**, When you publish your application you should use your own **Ads Ids**.

[Check This](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/test-ads)

Comment: i use test id for testing ad, but when i use my own id is does not work. if my game is not publish but i use my own id it would or not show AD properly?